# How to convert datetime.time into datetime.date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe called pomi that looks like this

```
date time sub 
2019-09-20 00:00:00 25.0 org
```

I want to convert the values in the column 'date' to datetime.date, so that I'm left with only the dates (ie '2019-09-20').

I have tried:

```
pomi['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pomi['date'])

pomi['just_date'] = pomi['date'].dt.date

pomi.date = pd.to_datetime(pomi.date,dayfirst=True)

pomi['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pomi["date"].astype(str)).dt.time

pomi['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pomi['date']).dt.date

pomi['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pomi['date']).dt.normalize()
```

None of them have worked.

Most often I get the error message "TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime"

All help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How many columns these are ? Is 25 goes into time & 'org' into sub column?

Comment: There are 3 columns: 'date', 'time' (the amount of time I spent on an activity, integer) and 'sub'.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - you already have a date column, no? If you need datetime functionality, just `pomi['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pomi['date'])`. pandas does not handle date and time separately.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure, I am not 100% sure what is the issue, your code was working fine at my end. But there is something you can try as convert to Timestamp & than check. This & your code both works at my end giving required out.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-09-20 00:00:00'], 'time':[25], 'sub':['org']})

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.Timestamp)

df['just_date'] = df['date'].dt.date

df
```

Comment: No need for apply (unnecessary iteration), use pd.to_datetime

Comment: Yeah I agree, I saw OP used it already & I also tested OP's code at my end it was working fine (as I mentioned in my answer). It is something extra to try

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this is the response I get:

Cannot convert input [00:00:00] of type <class 'datetime.time'> to Timestamp

Comment: I created the df by reading an xlsx file. In the file, the dates have no times - but in the resultant df, they appear as datetime.time.